# FFMPEG output frame name issue

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, jpeg, sequence

I'm going to convert DPX sequence of files to JPG sequence.

```
ffmpeg -i F:\test\my_files.%07d.dpx  F:\test2\my_files.%07d.jpg  -report
```

DPX files starts from zero frame (example: `my_files.0000000.dpx`), but JPG files after ffmpeg conversion get name that starts from first frame (example: `my_files.0000001.jpg`).

How to get name of JPG files start from zero frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i F:\test\my_files.%07d.dpx -start_number 0 F:\test2\my_files.%07d.jpg
```

The `image2` muxer's default value for `start_number` is 1.